# Easy way to graphically notify the user, that a program has finished

Tags: python, notifications

This seems to be a basic question, but the tricky part is, that I want that to work without having to care for any sort of GUI (if possible).

So, I have a program, that runs for some time, while I do other stuff. Which possibilities do you see, to notify the user, that the program has finished (let's stick to graphical hints, while sounds, mails, sms could be interesting elsewhere)?

Is there an easy way, to get e.g. a popup message, bringing the shell-window on top or else from within python without having to use a GUI?

I'm working right now in the gnome-shell with ipython. But other answers suitable for idle or spyder seem also to be interesting.

Comment: the best way is to use a GUI or to play a sound...

Answer (score 1):

GUI is the *simplest* and the *most effective*:

First of all install `easygui` from [here](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) and then try this code:

```
import easygui

easygui.msgbox("This is a message!", title="simple gui")
```

For more GUI programming in python [this tutorial is very helpful...](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=42)

If you don't want to do any GUI then you can do the following:
You can basically play an alerting sound to the user:

```
 def playSound():
     counter = 0
     while(counter < 10):
         print '\7'
         counter += 1

 #on completion of task
 playSound()
```

Comment: As far as I see, this is with the help of a GUI.

Comment: sorry, your question was unclear, by `without having to care for any sort of GUI (if possible).` i thought you meant a simple way of doing a gui

Comment: so can you please tell me what **exactly** you want? GUI is STILL the best option.. The least complicated and the most effective...

Comment: Your question title itself says, **Graphically** @Dschoni

Comment: I wanted the question to be as open as possible. Maybe there's a way to just bring a wingow (f.e. the shell in which the programm is running) on top or else. Or maybe a systemwide notification tool...?

Comment: If you have a soundcard yes ;) But my question is: What can I do graphically without using a GUI (can I somehow mess with open windows, rearange, show desktop....) from within python?